# How to add values in a cell with values?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a value in a cell, to which I want to add another value and display that new value.

Example:

- In cell A1 I have "1000".
- In Cell A2 I have "100".

I want A2 to add to A1. This way A1 would be "1100".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify the setting of your sheet, because the needed calculation is iterative.
Put this calculation in A1:

```
=If(B1,A1+A2,1000)
```

[image: sheet settings]
[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1awreSIMMh2_KUElVhjtl-l3b3E9jlWcHexYQ5ymJjn4/edit?usp=sharing)